# Python to find rows whose n-th column starts with aaa

Tags: python, csv

I have a tab-delimited txt file like this:

```
A   B   aaaKP
C   D   bbbZ
```

This is tab-delimited.

If

```
phrase = aaa
column = 3
```

then I would like only those rows whose 3rd column starts with aaa

The output will be

```
A   B   aaaKP
```

What I have tried is quite tedious, and I only tried MatLab.

I could try it only by using very slow if and for statements and findstr.

I could find no way better using MatLab.

Comment: That's nice.  I prefer python over Matlab as well.  How about showing us what you've tried in python?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
phrase, column = 'aaa', 3
fn = lambda l : len(l) >= column and len(l[column-1]) >= len(phrase) and phrase == l[column-1][:len(phrase)]
fp = open('output.txt', 'w')
fp.write(''.join(row for row in open('input.txt') if fn(row.split('\t'))))
fp.close()
```

Comment: Thank you! It prints the output correctly. Can I save the output as output.txt ?

Comment: Thank you it works! What if there are multiple phrases? For example what if I want to get rows whose 3rd column is either aaa or bbb or ccc ?   I tried "phrase, column = {'aaa','bbb','ccc'}, 3"   but  it didn't work.

Answer (score 0):

The simplest method I can think of:

```
with open('tab-delimited.txt', 'r') as f:
    for l in f:
       if l.split('\t')[2][:3] == 'aaa':
            print(l)
```

If you need help understanding python slicing, see [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/a/509295/2801037).